# Why don't these two table join in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using the below code to import [these sample Kaggle data sets](https://www.kaggle.com/secareanualin/football-events) for Python pratice):

```
# importing everything 
import pandas as pd
df_events = pd.DataFrame()
df_ginf = pd.DataFrame()
df_events = pd.read_csv('./events.csv')
df_ginf = pd.read_csv('./ginf.csv')

# creating a match table
eventsList = pd.Series(['On Target', 'Off Target', 'Blocked', 'Hit the Bar'])
eventListKey = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', '4'])
eventsMatchTable = pd.concat([eventListKey, eventsList], axis = 1)
eventsMatchTable.columns = ['eventKey', 'eventName']
eventsMatchTable['eventKey'] = eventsMatchTable['eventKey'].astype(int)

# trimming the initial dataframe down to something more manageable
df_eventsPlayer = pd.DataFrame()
df_eventsPlayer = df_events[['player', 'event_team', 'opponent', 'shot_place', 'shot_outcome', 'is_goal']]
df_eventsPlayer = df_eventsPlayer.dropna()
df_eventsPlayer['shot_outcome'] = 
df_eventsPlayer['shot_outcome'].astype(int)

# attempting the 'merge', here is where the error occurs
df_eventPlayerFinal = pd.DataFrame()
df_eventPlayerFinal = pd.merge(df_eventsPlayer, eventsMatchTable, how = 'left', on = ['shot_outcome','eventKey'])
df_eventPlayerFinal
```

The error says, roughly:
    KeyError: 'shot_outcome'
    # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

Because the columns I want to merge on are both `int`, this error does not make sense to me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns have different names, thus you can't use `on`. It should be specified which dataset contains given column:

```
pd.merge(df_eventsPlayer, eventsMatchTable, how = 'left',
         left_on = 'shot_outcome', right_on='eventKey')
```

Parameter `on` is used when **both** datasets contain specified columns

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago and it was caused by some NA values, my solution was to call `DataFrame.fillna`.

Answer (score 0):

`df_eventsPlayer['shot_outcome'] =`
you have to put something after the `=`